# Bearer Token from Microsoft has invalid signature

Tags: c#, azure, rest, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I want to implement a client credential flow with Azure. I have registered two apps in Azure(MyApi and MyClient). The app from myClient sends a POST-request to MS to get the token. I send a request with this token to the Rest-API server. The answer is always 401 Unauthorized - Baerer error="invalid_token" error_description="The signature is invalid".

This is my setup in Azure:

MyApi

Client ID: client_id_MyApi

Tenant ID: tenant_id

Application ID URI: api://MyApi

API-Permissions: Microsoft.Graph -> User.Read

Expose an API -> Scopes: api://MyApi/accessAsUser
App roles: accessAsApplication

MyClient

Client ID: client_id_MyClient
Tenant ID: tenant_id

Api-Permissions: Microsoft.Graph -> User.Read, MyApi -> accessAsApplication

Config of the REST-API Server:

```
Program.cs
...
builder.Services
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.Audience = client id of MyClient;
    o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenenat_id/";
    o.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    

});
...
```

FooController.cs

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("Foo")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task Foo()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Post-Request to get a token from Microsoft:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1

POST-Body:

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=client_id_MyClient&client_secret=mysecret&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Comment: Have you checked for typos in code? I spot 2 of them; Baerer and tenenat_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: Microsoft Graph API token is not meant to be validated that is the **aud** `https://graph.microsoft.com` as it is not meant for the application.

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, I got **Invalid Signature error**:

[image]

**Hence** you can avoid validating the access token for Microsoft Graph API.

You can validate the **access token for your own API** or application:

```json
scope: api://ClientID/.default
```

[image]

*Now I am able to validate the access token:*

[image]

**Reference:**

[spring security - Verify Signature with Azure AD - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69266224/verify-signature-with-azure-ad) by junnas