# Azzure AD JWT validation: signature verification failed

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, jwt, fastapi

i stumbled in a problem, i have this JWT verification code:

```
def validate_access_token(self, access_token):
        jwks_url = f"{self.authority}/discovery/v2.0/keys"

        # Fetch keys from the JWKS endpoint
        response = requests.get(jwks_url)
        jwks_data = response.json()

        # Extract and store Azure AD public keys
        azure_ad_keys = {}
        for key in jwks_data["keys"]:
            key_id = key["kid"]
            # Extract the x509 certificate
            x5c_cert = key["x5c"][0]
            # Convert x509 certificate to PEM format
            pem_cert = f"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n{x5c_cert}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
            azure_ad_keys[key_id] = pem_cert
        # Decode the access token
        print(azure_ad_keys)    
        try:
            token_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(access_token)
            logging.debug(f"Token header: {token_header}")
            token_kid = token_header["kid"]
            token_alg = token_header["alg"]
            
            public_key = azure_ad_keys[token_kid]
            logging.debug(f"Token kid: {token_kid}, Token alg: {token_alg}, public key: {public_key}")
            payload = jwt.decode(
                token=access_token, 
                key=public_key, 
                algorithms=[token_alg])
            logging.debug(f"Token payload: {payload}")
        except JWTError as e:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail=f"Invalid access token: {e}")

        # Validate token claims
        if payload["iss"] != f"{self.authority}/v2.0":
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid token issuer")

        if payload["aud"] != self.client_id:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid token audience")

        if payload["exp"] < time.time():
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Access token expired")

        return payload
```

it is returning "Invalid access token: Signature verification failed"

this is my JWT:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IjVETWxPSjV4T1BrZUZ4bnE3QVJVZDl2Uy1taGYwc09Qb290NGRaTlViVkkiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtXYmthYTZxczh3c1RuQndpaU5ZT2hIYm5BdyIsImtpZCI6ImtXYmthYTZxczh3c1RuQndpaU5ZT2hIYm5BdyJ9.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.sQKGfmYPFCarHwx1hMKbgJsTmlSMt8-Sg491w0DWWXE1ZjXBLdOSbuEJjTEpNj0VG-YSuN1SR-fs44D969bGaKD4UvZBAAm8gJIm5inkGp6-x_3WL3VMmUz3nMthgFKocNcxp7HwOqn7Gsj_oiTzNMveD5YgT3SXvrgXQQFzG1eNNT8WsN1NCa1nanFO789yaqXdjaDQbo5HKqyg9xwrKp-n6fpsFQjWXesr3GFZLHNt1tTMAnjOY_hzQ9xSVGdd7z7FAacM_NlLQZVhvD0iDp2D4nFXQWHAy9qDuk8u-6U9jcweQYubw68W2oP3gYvMqacZKTr8z70iE9sF0uujrQ
```

this is my debug log:

```
DEBUG:root:Token header: {'typ': 'JWT', 'nonce': '5DMlOJ5xOPkeFxnq7ARUd9vS-mhf0sOPoot4dZNUbVI', 'alg': 'RS256', 'x5t': 'kWbkaa6qs8wsTnBwiiNYOhHbnAw', 'kid': 'kWbkaa6qs8wsTnBwiiNYOhHbnAw'}
DEBUG:root:Token kid: kWbkaa6qs8wsTnBwiiNYOhHbnAw, Token alg: RS256, public key: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
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
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

although i have matching public key and algorithm, it still cannot verify the signature.
Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ***"Invalid access token: Signature verification failed"*** usually occurs if you are trying to validate Microsoft Graph API access token.

- The Microsoft Graph API access token that is **aud** as `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` or `https://graph.mircosoft.com` is not meant to be validated as it is not meant for the application.
- Hence, there is no need to validate the access token for Microsoft Graph API as it doesn't contain a "nonce" in the JWT Header and is not meant to be validated.
- You can validate access token **access token for your own API** or application.

When I tried to validate the access token, I got the **same error**:

[image]

The **aud** is Microsoft Graph:

[image]

I tried to validate the access token for my own API and it is successful:

I used **`scope: api://ClientID/.default`** to generate access token.

```py
import jwt
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import json
import requests

access_token = 'YourAccessToken'
response = requests.get(f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/discovery/keys")
keys = response.json()['keys']

token_headers = jwt.get_unverified_header(access_token)
token_alg = token_headers['alg']
token_kid = token_headers['kid']
public_key = None
for key in keys:
     if key['kid'] == token_kid:
         public_key = key 

rsa_pem_key = jwt.algorithms.RSAAlgorithm.from_jwk(json.dumps(public_key))
rsa_pem_key_bytes = rsa_pem_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM, 
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
) 

decoded_token = jwt.decode(
    access_token, 
    key=rsa_pem_key_bytes,
    verify=True,
    options={"verify_signature": True},
    algorithms=['RS256'],
    audience="ClientID",
    issuer=f"https://sts.windows.net/TenantID/"
)
s = json.dumps(decoded_token)
q = json.dumps(json.loads(s), indent=2)
print(q)
```

**The access token validated successfully:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[spring security - Verify Signature with Azure AD - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69266224/verify-signature-with-azure-ad)  by junnas

Comment: so, after i successfully get MS Graph Access Token, i should generate my own access token and use it accross the service? and when i need to validate access token and refresh token, i should validate my own token (not MS Graph token)?

Comment: Yes if you want Microsoft graph access token then you can use it directly without validating it

Comment: for security reason what is the best approach? to directly use ms graph access token or generate my own token after successfuly retrieve msd graph access token? (sorry for the noob question, we have just move our identity management server from other product to azzure AD)

Comment: It's completely based on your requirement the API you want to call

Comment: @galih there is no harm in generating Microsoft Graph Api token

Comment: as for now my requirement doesnt need users to directly interact with ms graph API, (all interaction is being handled by daemon service), but for simplicity, if i wanted to directly use ms graph api access token as user access token, this should be okay right? thans sir

Comment: Yeah it is okay no issues in doing that