Using Azure AD as Identitidy Provider in KeyCloak
I have integrated the client's Azure AD in KeyCloak.
Unfortunately in profile data we are not receiving email but when I have decoded the Bearertoken..it has all the information I need.
In Identitiy provider settings..If I select Verify JWT Token, its throwing Verification Signature failed error, if I un select and try to login..it is looking for mapper email which is not found in profile dump json data.
Client is complaining that response_type=code in the request url instead of responstype=code id_token which is the reason I am not receiving the email in the profile data.
Can anyone suggest how can I get full profle data by updating response_type=code id_token please. Unfortunately I am unable to find such setting in identity provider.
--this is how I have added a upn mapper in Azure Id Identity Provider:


Actually..we are implementing openId and the example is SAML. But I have followed similar steps like above but no success.

I added Azure AD as identity provider in my Key Cloak server with below settings:

Now, I registered one Entra ID application by adding above redirect URI in Web platform like this:

Initially, I added openid profile as scopes in Azure AD identity provider as below:

Now, I ran the sign in flow again where it has Azure AD as alternate option to login as below:

After successful authentication, I checked user's profile which does not have email field mapped like this:

To get email in user's profile, make sure to add email in Scopes of identity provider by editing it as below:

When I signed in again by deleting previous user, new user created with email in profile successfully like this:

Reference:
Keycloak: Map email from Azure AD to auto created Keycloak Users - Stack Overflow by Vitaly

could you inform me what is the first login override you have used please, also could you post your advance settings please. I am getting 2024-06-25 13:55:29,198 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (executor-thread-48) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: token signature validation failed

Note that, when you are using Microsoft Graph scopes like openid, profile, email you cannot validate the token as it gives Signature validation failed error. Refer  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77988462/azzure-ad-jwt-validation-signature-verification-failed/77992306#77992306. I followed this blog to add Azure AD as identity provider in Key Cloak https://medium.com/@yasithkumara/using-azure-active-directory-as-an-identity-provider-in-keycloak-81e7cd8bd1bd

Understood..whats the First login flow you have selected please.

actually it is working when the Azure profile has email, but when the profile like below which is not having email, then it is not working. But when I decode the bearer token, it has upn and unique_name (both are having email ids). Added mapper also, but no success. example of my profile: 2024-06-26 14:55:27,513 DEBUG [org.keycloak.social.user_profile_dump] (executor-thread-21) User Profile JSON Data for provider DB-SSO: {"sub":"i25A21oOsT9GQBOR8hSXp7vxIS7v7ef8FCy-YnWN5N8","name":"Raja","family_name":"Sekhar","given_name":"Raja","picture":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"}

If email is not found in Azure profile,  configure a mapper to use the upn attribute. This involves creating a user attribute mapper in the Azure AD identity provider settings within Keycloak, mapping the upn claim to the email attribute. Could you include how you added the mapper by editing your question with images?

Updated question with upn mapper.
